# Align custom painted text in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need make custom widget (in Flutter) which contains text on specific position. When I draw text by TextPainter, I set TextAlign to center. Text is still drawn with left align. What am I doing wrong?

```
TextSpan span = TextSpan(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: textSize), text: 'T');
TextPainter tp = TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.center, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout();
tp.paint(canvas, Offset(pos.x, pos.y));
```

Comment: see what params you can pass to `layout` method

Comment: From doc: `layout({double minWidth: 0.0, double maxWidth: double.infinity }) → void'`. Alignment does not work without width limitations?

Comment: set maxWidth to 200 and see what happens, then change it to 400 and compare the results

Comment: I tried it, but the position remained the same.

Comment: OK so what do you want to center? and center against what? your text is only "T"?

Comment: I want to draw a single line of text so that it is centered horizontally and vertically to a given point.

Comment: Yes, I draw only 'T' because I want to draw one character in the middle of the circle.

Comment: Thank you, this works :) Do you know what the textAlign parameter of the TextPainter class does?

Comment: it aligns the text horizontally when the width is specified

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the X position make sure layout is set to 0 for min an max width

```
textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 0);
```

for the Y position you have to substract the height of the text itself

```
final position = Offset(xPOS, yPOS - (textPainter.height / 2));
```

here is an example code

```
void _drawTextAt(String text, Offset position, Canvas canvas) {
    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 30,
    );
    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: 'O',
      style: textStyle,
    );
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: textSpan,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);
    textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 0);
    Offset drawPosition =
        Offset(position.dx, position.dy - (textPainter.height / 2));
    textPainter.paint(canvas, drawPosition);
  }
```

To use this function call e.g.

```
  _drawTextAt('A', Offset(20, 20), canvas);
```

Comment: hmm with the min/maxwidth as 0, it will just draw characters vertically. Fine if you just have one char, but otherwise for me letters go vertically, not horizontally. I suspect you may want maxWidth to be double.infinity and x in the Offset to be position.dx - textPainter.width / 2 ?

Answer (score 20):

[image: Align a custom painted text with CustomPainter in Flutter]

To simply center the text on the canvas, calculate its offset:

```dart
void _paintText(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final textSpan = TextSpan(
    text: 'n/a',
  );
  final textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: textSpan,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  );
  textPainter.layout();
  textPainter.paint(
    canvas,
    Offset(
      // Do calculations here:
      (size.width - textPainter.width) * 0.5,
      (size.height - textPainter.height) * 0.5,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: May I know why you multiplied with 0.5?

Comment: @BalajiRamadoss `size.width * 0.5` is the center of the canvas. To find a start of my text span, I deduct `textPainter.width * 0.5`, which is equal to `(size.width - textPainter.width) * 0.5`

Answer (score 3):

By using `Alignment.inscribe`, you can align the text in any way. :)

```
extension CanvasExt on Canvas {
    void drawTextInRect(
        Rect rect,
        Alignment alignment,
        TextPainter painter,
    ) {
        final offsetRect = alignment.inscribe(painter.size, rect);
        painter.paint(this, offsetRect.topLeft);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
double width = 100, height = 200, r = 63;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(width, height), r, Paint()..color = Colors.purple);
    ParagraphBuilder paragraphBuilder =
        ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(textAlign: TextAlign.center))
          ..addText('Hello');
    ParagraphConstraints paragraphConstraints =
        ParagraphConstraints(width: r * 2);
    Paragraph paragraph = paragraphBuilder.build()
      ..layout(paragraphConstraints);
    canvas.drawParagraph(
        paragraph, Offset(width - r, height - paragraph.height / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used drawParagraph and it works well

```
final ui.ParagraphBuilder paragraphBuilder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
        ui.ParagraphStyle(textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr),
      )
      ..addText('Your Text');
final ui.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphBuilder.build()
        ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: textSize.width));
canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, textOffset);
```

you can change the ParagraphStyle the way you like.

Comment: where did you get the `textSize` and `textOffset`?

Comment: The offset and size of area where you want to paint the text in the canvas